# Show "Sign Up with" in landing page

Tags: registration, landing-page

At my company we're planning to redesign our landing page. Currently we have two big buttons, "Sign up" and "Sign up with Linkedin".

One idea that came up is to remove the Linkedin button. When the user clicks on "Sign up" we navigate to another page where there's the possibility to continue with Linkedin or enter your data manually.

My question is: will this discourage users to register? If I see a Linkedin button I may think "Cool I don't have to enter any data". If the button is not there I might think the process is too long.

Is there any study about this?

Comment: Can you, perhaps, add an example of what you've got so far? :-)

Comment: Thought about SO's signup page? Paste the URL in different browser - https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of clicks to get somewhere has already been disproven many times; so in light of that, its good as long as the user gets the sense of going forward.

That being said, I think just "sign up" is enough, as, like you mentioned, you can give people several options to register on the following view (not limited to linkedin even). I think the real question is, how do you convince people to click on the register button, because, if I don't trust the site, I'm not giving my personally info, let alone my linkedin.

What you can do, however, is make it very convenient to register, for instance, at the bottom of each site or as a bottom banner on your "sales-pitch" pages (the pages that explain what benefit the user has from registering).
As always, it depends on your use-case; sites like FB/LinkedIn need users and lots of it, so they slap you in the face with an easy to use sign up process :-), but they have a different use-case than StackExchange, for instance, that wants to share great information in the first place :-)

You can definitly A/B test this one and see if it makes a difference.

sources:

- http://www.nngroup.com/articles/conversion-rates/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_foraging

interesting reading material:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimizing-mobile-registration-process-scott-richards
- http://uxmovement.com/forms/8-reasons-users-arent-filling-out-your-sign-up-form/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have the sign up on the landing page itself without directing the user to another place. That way you can have the Sign up via Linked in as a second option. Also try to avoid long sign up form. Just have 2 fields, may be for the name and email address and the sign up button.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to legal reasons, we have a quite long form

Comment: It'll be easier to explain if you could add a wireframe of your form

Comment: This is the form. The fields change depending on which option you choose at the top. So we have 3 type of users. When they arrive on the landing page I don't know what type they are.